# Dynamical body in FastApi using Pydantic

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I would like to have a dynamical mandatory body on FastApi.

I explain :

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Body
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class Parameters(BaseModel):
    platform: str
    country: str

@app.put("/myroute")
async def provision_instance(*, parameters: Parameters = Body(...)):
    do_something

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

Here, my body is manually defined in the Parameters class with two attributes, platform and country.
In the future, these attributes will come from a configuration file and there will be more than two attributes. So I will need to create them automatically on the fly.

For example, in the configuration file, I could have :

```
---
parameters:
  application:
    description: "Name of the application"
    type: string
  platform:
    description: "Name of the platform"
    type: string
  country:
    description: "Name of the country"
    type: string
```

How could I have in this context a variable number of parameters required in the body ? Should I find a way to give to my Parameters class a variable number of attributes ?

Answer (score 2):

Pydantic models can be built dynamically as described in [this section](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation) of the documentation. You would still have to implement a function that will read your yaml file and build the Pydantic model from it.

---

Now consider a few Pydantic models in a python file ; aren't this equivalent to having a yaml file describing models ?

---

If you came up with with this plan of dynamically building Pydantic models because you will have multiple shape of data coming in, you might also explore using [`typing.Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) for defining your endpoint :

```py
class Parameters1(BaseModel):
    platform: str
    country: str


class Parameters2(BaseModel):
    application: str
    country: str


@app.put("/myroute")
async def provision_instance(*, parameters: Union[Parameters1, Parameters2] = Body(...)):
    if isinstance(parameters, Parameters1):
        pass  # TODO
    elif isinstance(parameters, Parameters2):
        pass  # TODO
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas for your answer.
I really need to use an yaml configuration file.
Would you have an example where I could build a Pydantic model with dynamical keys ?

Comment: hey @Nico were you able to get around this?